# Pattern Error of Email of HTML5 in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form so when user click on edit button then the text replace with input type="email" and also matches the given patterns of email

```
               <label for="name-c">Email-Id:</label>
             <label class="email">abc@xyz.com</label>
                 <button class="edit">edit</button>
```

Jquery code:

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
  var email=$('.email').text();
   $('.email').replaceWith(function () {
     var pattern = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/;
     return '<input type="email" id="email" name="email" title="Enter email like abc@xyz.com" required placeholder="abc@xyz.com"   pattern="' + pattern + '"'+'class="ui-input-text ui-body-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset"/>'});
     $('#email').val(email);});
```

I am getting error message please type the given pattern though it is right.
But when I matching by simple placing by `input type="email"` followed by pattern then its matching.I totally confused where my code is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't need a pattern. When you specified the `type="email"` it is the navigator which control the value. I test [here][1] with the default param and it works for me with chrome and firefox. But when I add a pattern like ".*" the check fails it is curious.

Int the specification given by W3C they allow the attribute pattern but when you scroll down to [value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html#input.email.attrs.value.single) they the value is check with a specified value.

So you don't need to add the pattern the check is implicit.

EDIT :

Try with this regexp ^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+$ I take the regexp defined in w3c specifcation and I change the final * by a +.

EDIT :

Finally I found the mistake in fact it misses a backslashes when you add the input with jquery here the solution http://jsfiddle.net/KaBut/6/

Comment: Try to give abc@xyz it also accepting this value too which is wrong

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KaBut/1/ jquery example doesn't work and html works fine. I don't understand why but I'm sure the rexexp is good.

Comment: it misses a double backslash. After click on edit button I inspected the input to see the pattern and I saw it missed the backslash before the dot at the pattern's end. For the w3c an email can be intern it is the reason of the * at the end of the regexp. For example on your PC charles.jourdan@localhost is a valid email.

Comment: you ommit to doublebackslash your dot and I don't test if put in string or not change the result.